# split datetime column into date and time columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a following question. I have a date_time column in my dataframe (and many other columns).

```
df["Date_time"].head()
0    2021-05-15 09:54
1    2021-05-27 17:04
2    2021-05-27 00:00
3    2021-05-27 09:36
4    2021-05-26 18:39
Name: Date_time, dtype: object
```

I would like to split this column into two (date and time).

I use this formula that works fine:

```
df["Date"] = ""
df["Time"] = ""

def split_date_time(data_frame):
    for i in range(0, len(data_frame)):
        df["Date"][i] = df["Date_time"][i].split()[0]
        df["Time"][i] = df["Date_time"][i].split()[1]

split_date_time(df)
```

But is there a more elegant way? Thanks

Comment: You can do `df[["Date","Time"]] = df["Date_time"].str.split(expand=True)` if you simply want to split them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`dt` accessor can give you [`date`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.date.html) and [`time`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.time.html) separately:

```
df["Date"] = df["Date_time"].dt.date
df["Time"] = df["Date_time"].dt.time
```

to get

```
>>> df

            Date_time        Date      Time
0 2021-05-15 09:54:00  2021-05-15  09:54:00
1 2021-05-27 17:04:00  2021-05-27  17:04:00
2 2021-05-27 00:00:00  2021-05-27  00:00:00
3 2021-05-27 09:36:00  2021-05-27  09:36:00
4 2021-05-26 18:39:00  2021-05-26  18:39:00
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, but it does not work: `AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values`

Comment: @vojtam Yes; you need to have a datetime-like series that are not only strings, so please do `df["Date_time"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date_time"])` prior to above code.